# Good fit vs. Best fit - Lower end of the fit range (Difference of 1 cm). Is it OK? or can this tiny difference still cause pains?

Tags: road-bike, frames, bike-fit, pain, trek

I want to buy a second hand Trek Cronus (Gary Fischer Collection) bike (50cms) for my wife. I am getting a good deal on it. My wife's height is 156cms. As per the Trek Sizing chart, the range of rider height for a 50cms bike is from 157cms to 165cms. So technically the perfect fit for 50cms looks like 161cms.

So, my query is that would a 1 cm difference (her height of 156cms vs fit starting from 157cms) matter in causing any kind of pains (knee, back etc.) for her in the long run for her? I would ideally like her to go for her perfect fit of 47cms Trek bike. However, this second hand carbon fiber bike with Shimano 105 components is priced at the same rate as a new Trek One series 1.1 with a Shimano Claris components. That's the main pull.

Also, on a side note, how is the Trek Cronus (Gary Fischer Collection) bike? I tried to read reviews. But I did not find many for this particular model as I found for the regular Domanes, Emondas etc.

I tried to search the site if a similar query had been posted i.e. with this close a fit (1 cm) difference. I did not find any. Hence my post.

Thanks to let me know.

[image]

Comment: For the same height, the fit is going to depend heavily on her proportions. If she's long-limbed it will feel very different to if she's long in the body

Comment: If you are at the lower end of a height group the general opinion is to chose the smaller size. But as @Chris H says limb and torso dimension also play a part. Height isn't the only factor.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the comments. I will then accordingly check in the store for the correct fit. If the 50cm can be fit to her height then maybe I can consider this. Better to have a good fit and lower spec bike rather than a great bike and a painful body later..

Comment: Bike fit is a "qualified estimate"  a bike frame's size is known but what heights that suits is an "approximation"  Combine two estimates and all you do is increase the margin of error/the fade in-out part.   None of those ranges are a hard cutoff.    You need to get the rider to try the bike.   **A good deal is not a good deal if its a bad fit**

Answer (score 1):

The sizing chats provided by manufacturers are only really a guide. One should never pick a size based on them alone.

The only way to select a correctly sized frame is to test ride bikes of different frame sizes. As mentioned in comments, body proportions make a big difference.

Don't approach a possibly too-large discounted bike with the mindset of 'can I make this work?' Get the bike that is right in the first place. There will be other deals that come along. Also, remember that with a used bike you'll be doing maintenance and replacing wear items such as the chain and cassette sooner than with a new one.

Comment: Ok.. THanks for you input. I will surely test ride the bikes to check which fits better.